# (Discord.py) correct way to return value from button selection?

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord import Embed
from discord.ui import View


class Button_solve(View):
    def __init__(self, channel):
        super().__init__(timeout=60)
        self.channel = channel

    @discord.ui.button(label="1", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id="button1")
    async def callback_1(self, interaction, button):
        button.label += " ✅"
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
        global proceed
        proceed = 1

    @discord.ui.button(label="2", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="button2")
    async def callback_2(self, interaction, button):
        button.label += " ✅"
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
        global proceed
        proceed = 2

    @discord.ui.button(label="3", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id="button3")
    async def callback_3(self, interaction, button):
        button.label += " ✅"
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
        global proceed
        proceed = 3


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send(embed=Embed(title="Select Button"), content="", view=Button_solve(channel))
    if proceed == 1:
        # process
    if proceed == 2: 
        # process
    if proceed == 3:
        # process


client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

This code sends a message of three buttons and the selected button determines `proceed`. However since `await channel.send` is asynchronous, it goes straight into `if proceed == 1` before the user selects the button and makes an error. Any ideas for addressing this issue? The best solution is probably returning the selected value of the button straightforwardly, but I cannot find a method for this.

To note, I am not considering

```
if proceed == 1:
elif proceed == 2: 
elif proceed == 3:
```

this part inside each `async def callback` function in `class Button_solve(View)` because it gets way too complex in the original code.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I've found a solution while looking at [an example code here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/confirm.py).

```
import discord
from discord import Embed
from discord.ui import View


class Button_solve(View):
    def __init__(self, channel):
        super().__init__(timeout=60)
        self.channel = channel
        self.value = None

    @discord.ui.button(label="1", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id="button1")
    async def callback_1(self, interaction, button):
        button.label += " ✅"
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
        self.value = 1
        self.stop()

    @discord.ui.button(label="2", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="button2")
    async def callback_2(self, interaction, button):
        button.label += " ✅"
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
        self.value = 2
        self.stop()

    @discord.ui.button(label="3", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id="button3")
    async def callback_3(self, interaction, button):
        button.label += " ✅"
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
        self.value = 3
        self.stop()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send(embed=Embed(title="Select Button"), content="", view=Button_solve(channel))
    await view.wait()

    if view.value == 1:
        # process
    elif view.value == 2: 
        # process
    elif view.value == 3:
        # process
```